# Determinant prove (Faster method to solve it)

Tags: determinant

**Question:**

I know how to solve this problem but I need a faster approach to this problem.

> By using properties of determinants prove that the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}a & \sin x & \cos x \\ -\sin x & -a & 1 \\ \cos x & 1 & a\end{vmatrix}$$ is independent of $x$.

**My Approach:**

> \begin{align*} \text{LHS} &= \begin{vmatrix}a & \sin x & \cos x \\ -\sin x & -a & 1 \\ \cos x & 1 & a\end{vmatrix}
> \\&= -a^3 \begin{vmatrix}1 & \dfrac{\sin x}{a} & \dfrac{\cos x}{a} \\ \dfrac{\sin x}{a} & a & \dfrac{-1}{a} \\ \dfrac{\cos x}{a} & \dfrac{1}{a} & 1\end{vmatrix}\begin{array}{l}\text{Taking a common $a$ from $R_1$}\\\text{Taking a common $-a$ from $R_2$}\\\text{Taking a common $a$ from $R_3$}\end{array}\end{align*}

[image: 2nd part of my solution]

Comment: "Your approach" seems unfinished - what you have still depends on $x$. Can you please post a complete question before anyone attempts to answer it?

Comment: Yes please wait.

Comment: @user8734617 I have edited it.

Comment: Try just taking the determinant without messing around with the terms or factoring, and then trying to cancel/simplify terms with $x$.  You should only need to use one easy trig identity.

Comment: @Carl but the question demands using the properties.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer You expand in your solution too, so if expanding is fine there's no reason not to expand immediately.  Trying to do it without expanding seems silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the "criss-cross" method for a $3\times3$ determinant
$$\left|\matrix{a&b&c\cr d&e&f\cr g&h&i\cr}\right|=aei+bfg+cdh-ceg-afh-bdi$$
you can just write down the answer:
$$\eqalign{\det(\hbox{your matrix})
  &=-a^3+\cos x\sin x-\sin x\cos x+a\cos^2x+a\sin^2x-a\cr
  &=-a^3\ .\cr}$$
I really doubt you'll get anything faster than that.

---

If you haven't seen the "criss-cross" method before, it is easy to remember: copy out the first two columns again, add up these three products
$$\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
  \left|\matrix{\c a&b&c\cr d&\c e&f\cr g&h&\c i\cr}\right|\matrix{a&b\cr d&e\cr g&h\cr}\qquad
  \left|\matrix{a&\c b&c\cr d&e&\c f\cr g&h&i\cr}\right|\matrix{a&b\cr d&e\cr \c g&h\cr}\qquad
  \left|\matrix{a&b&\c c\cr d&e&f\cr g&h&i\cr}\right|\matrix{a&b\cr \c d&e\cr g&\c h\cr}$$
and subtract these three products
$$\def\c#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
  \left|\matrix{a&b&\c c\cr d&\c e&f\cr \c g&h&i\cr}\right|\matrix{a&b\cr d&e\cr g&h\cr}\qquad
  \left|\matrix{a&b&c\cr d&e&\c f\cr g&\c h&i\cr}\right|\matrix{\c a&b\cr d&e\cr g&h\cr}\qquad
  \left|\matrix{a&b&c\cr d&e&f\cr g&h&\c i\cr}\right|\matrix{a&\c b\cr \c d&e\cr g&h\cr}$$
But **NOTE** that it only works for the $3\times3$ case.

Comment: Your solution is great bro.You are really genius.May you get further success in this subject.